# $C_2\amalg C_3$ is not $C_2\times C_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Aluffi asks the reader to use one-to-one homomorphisms from $C_2$ and $C_3$ to $S_3$ to prove that in $\mathsf{Grp}$, as opposed to $\mathsf{Ab}$, $C_2\amalg C_3 \ncong C_2\times C_3$. It's straightforward to prove that the usual injections $a\mapsto(a,0)$ and $b\mapsto(0,b)$ won't do the trick, and that may be all he's really looking for (the question is phrased rather vaguely), but I *think* he wants more. He hasn't gone into how coproducts of groups are found yet, so the answer should not involve actually calculating $C_2\amalg C_3$.

#### What I have so far

Let $x$ be a $2$-cycle in $S_3$, $y$ a $3$-cycle, and $e$ the identity.

Let $f\colon C_2\hookrightarrow S_3$, with $f([0]_2)=e$ and $f([1]_2)=x$. This is a homomorphism, and also (perhaps relevantly?) has a left inverse mapping even permutations to $[0]_2$ and odd ones to $[1]_2$. This implies the canonical injection $i_2$ must in fact be a categorical injection.

Let $g\colon C_3\to S_3$ with $g([1]_3)=y$. This has no left inverse, but the canonical injection $i_3$ is at least one-to-one.

By the definition of coproduct, there must be a unique $h\colon C_2\amalg C_3\to S_3$ such that $h\circ i_2=f$ and $h\circ i_3=g$. It appears that Aluffi is looking for a proof that there is no such $h\colon C_2\times C_3\to S_3$.

I'm slowly running out of ideas. Just need a small hint.

Comment: Doesn’t it just amount to finding a group $G$, preferably nonabelian I suppose, with maps from $C_2$ and $C_3$ into it so that the map of the coproduct into $G$ is onto? in other words so that the element of order $2$ and the element of order $3$ generate $G$?

Comment: To amplify Lubin's hint: The $h$ that you got near the end of your question will be surjective, because its image includes $x$ and $y$, which generate $S_3$. But there cannot be a surjection from an abelian group to a non-abelian one.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, is the answer below correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Lubin and Andreas Blass.

Let $p=i_2([1]_2)$ and $q=i_3([1]_3)$.

Then $yx=h(q)h(p)=h(qp)=h(pq)=h(p)h(q)=xy$, a contradiction.